# Disable submit button when duplicates in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In extending to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707131/check-duplicate-values-between-multiple-inputs-and-show-error-message) how to disable submit button or make form invalid if i have any duplicates

**Got Solution** : here is my code

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="redemptionStep1.$invalid">Submit</a>
```

JS

```
$scope.myform.$setValidity('invalid',!((sorted[i-1] && sorted[i-1].voucherCode == sorted[i].voucherCode) || (sorted[i+1] && sorted[i+1].voucherCode == sorted[i].voucherCode)));
```

Comment: Instead of updating question with solution you can answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your **Controller**

```
$scope.hasDuplicate = function() {
    var sorted;

    sorted = $scope.csTagGrp[0].csTags.concat().sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.keys > b.keys) return 1;
      if (a.keys < b.keys) return -1;
      return 0;
    });

    return sorted.some(function(nth, i){

        if(i> 0  && i < sorted.length) {
          return ((nth[i - 1].keys == nth.keys) || (sorted[i + 1].keys == nth.keys));
        }

        return false;

    });

  };
```

In template

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="hasDuplicate()"> Save </button>
```